# Realtek RTL8192CE started having connectivity issues

Tags: 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

A month or so ago I got a new machine. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

Everything worked perfectly until yesterday, when I started having intermittent connectivity issues from the wifi card (Realtek RTL8192CE). The connection seems to drop for seconds-minutes at a time, during which the card is still associated with the router, but I can't ping 8.8.8.8 or even the router. I know the router is up because I can access its web interface (and otherwise access the internet) from other devices.

Since I didn't touch the config or update Ubuntu at all, I suspect this is a hardware issue (although the effect seems to be less noticeable, if at all, when I dual-boot to Windows). However, I want to have a better diagnosis before I contact the seller for a replacement.

Any ideas how to diagnose this? In particular, how to figure out whether it's a hardware issue or a software issue?

Comment: Run this Wireless Info Script: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info , as described in this AskUbuntu post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205 . This will create the file "wireless-info.txt" at the location it is run from; then edit your original post, and copy paste the output from that TXT file. Info about the script, as mentioned in the post, "we created at the Ubuntu Forums to collect all the most common information needed while masking all sensitive data."